# Localization - agnostic output for netcat

Tags: netcat

I would like to use netcat to test if some ports are listening or not but, since the command will be executed in machines that will have languages different than English, it's not a great idea to `grep` its output based on the word `LISTENING` (for example, I saw on a German pc the word `ABHOREN`).

I tried to look at the manpages for netcat, but I can't seem to find a solution for that, so I was wondering if anybody ever managed to translate the status of the port into a numerical format, rather than a string.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you say LISTENING, I guess that you actually want to `netstat` (not `netcat`). Most modern systems understand `netstat -lnt` which only lists LISTENING tcp sockets, nothing else. Beware on minimal RHEL7 install there is no netstat - it is deprecated in favor of `ss` (same flags `ss -lnt` but slightly different output format).

In a general case the answer would be to set locale in the environment properly, this way all processes will talk to you in English (or better, C).

Comment: yes indeed, I was referring to `netstat` but typed it wrong. Too many hours on the terminal :)

Answer (score 2):

You can export the language for netcat before running it (or even for your whole script):

```
LANG=C netcat ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Like `netstat` you can ask the kernel directly. Its info comes from `/proc/net/tcp` and `/proc/net/tcp6`. Both files are formatted in the same way and are *slightly* (cough) harder to read that the `netstat` output, but are language independent

This is a chopped and slightly masked sample output:

```
$ cat /proc/net/tcp
  sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode
   0: 00000000:0385 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 5126 1 f4807080 100 0 0 10 -1
   1: 00000000:2328 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000   113        0 5264 1 f62ff540 100 0 0 10 -1
   2: 00000000:008B 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 4535 1 f5bf1540 100 0 0 10 -1
   9: 0200000A:08AE xxxxxxxx:D512 01 00000030:00000000 01:00000018 00000000     0        0 759198 4 f63e95c0 24 4 3 10 19
  10: 0200000A:0D9B xxxxxxxx:7582 01 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000   113        0 634192 1 f63e90c0 21 4 22 5 3
```

The key fields you're looking at at the hex following the `:` under `local_address` (Local port) and the `st` column (Status).

The status columns are referred to in the kernel source [`./include/net/tcp_states.h`](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/net/tcp_states.h?id=HEAD), but helpfully someone has asked the question over on StackExchange: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992211/list-of-possible-internal-socket-statuses-from-proc

I'll duplicate here for completeness:

```
enum {
    TCP_ESTABLISHED = 1,
    TCP_SYN_SENT,
    TCP_SYN_RECV,
    TCP_FIN_WAIT1,
    TCP_FIN_WAIT2,
    TCP_TIME_WAIT,
    TCP_CLOSE,
    TCP_CLOSE_WAIT,
    TCP_LAST_ACK,
    TCP_LISTEN,
    TCP_CLOSING,    /* Now a valid state */

    TCP_MAX_STATES  /* Leave at the end! */
};
```

As one of the comments states, this is an `enum` so the states are numbered sequentially from 1. Mostly you're looking for `0A` (LISTENING) and `01` (ESTABLISHED)

NB: To find out where netstat was getting this info from, I ran `strace -e open,write netstat -an`.

There's a deeper  dive into the field headers, here: http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/linux/2000/11/16/LinuxAdmin.html

Comment: OP didn't say "Linux" and other Unix-like don't have `/proc/net/`